# User defined folder paths in Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, user-input

am new to Grunt. Until this time i made a few tasks, compiler for less and sass, some watches.

I would like to have grunt in static folder, but when i start watch sequence i usually need to start it in folder where is my project placed = tons of separate grunts files and node-modules folders.

**What i need:** static folder for grunt and when i start it i will tell him as a user through console where i need him to watch files (which project). I need to set by user destinations and original folders.

**Is it possible in grunt?**

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but a common node pardadigm is to allow users to configure dynamic options through env vars.

To do this grunt could optionally accept and env var

`process.env.PATH_TO_WATCH || defaultPathToWatch`

If provided it will allow the starter of the grunt processes to specify a dynamic `PATH_TO_WATCH`.

`PATH_TO_WATCH=/some/path node start_grunt.js`